# Autocomplete decoration flutter

Tags: flutter, autocomplete

I am using an autocomplete widget in the form. I have a problem with the suggestion window. I wanted to make the corners of the suggestions rounded. I tried to add border to the Container, i tried InputDecorator and nothing are working.

Here is a code:

```
Form(
          key: _formkey,
          child: Autocomplete(
            optionsBuilder: (textEditingValue) {
              if (textEditingValue.text.isEmpty) {
                return const Iterable<String>.empty();
              } else {
                return autoCompleteList.where(
                  (word) => word.toLowerCase().contains(
                        textEditingValue.text.toLowerCase(),
                      ),
                );
              }
            },
            optionsViewBuilder: (context, onSelected, options) {
              return Align(
                alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                child: Material(
                  child: Container(
                    color: greyMed,
                    child: ConstrainedBox(
                      constraints:
                          const BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 300, maxWidth: 235),
                      child: ListView.builder(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          final option = options.elementAt(index);
                          return ListTile(
                            title: Text(
                              option.toString(),
                              style: TextStyle(color: textWhite),
                            ),
                            onTap: () {
                              onSelected(option);
                            },
                          );
                        },
                        itemCount: options.length,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
            fieldViewBuilder:
                (context, controller, focusNode, onFieldSubmitted) {
              return TextFormField(
                controller: controller,
                focusNode: focusNode,
                onEditingComplete: onFieldSubmitted,
                maxLines: 1,
                maxLength: 30,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value!.isEmpty) {
                    return 'Field is empty';
                  }
                  return null;
                },
                onSaved: (value) {
                  drillName = value!;
                },
                style: TextStyle(color: textWhite),
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                  enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                      Radius.circular(10),
                    ),
                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: grey),
                  ),
                  focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                      Radius.circular(10),
                    ),
                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: orange),
                  ),
                  filled: true,
                  fillColor: greyMed,
                  labelStyle: TextStyle(color: greyLight),
                  labelText: 'Drill name',
                ),
              );
            },
          )),
```

Do you have any ideas? Will be grateful for help.

Comment: tried `RawAutocomplete` already?

Comment: I tried RawAutocomplete

I wrap ListView.builder into container with fixed width and height. And I put border radius. This is the result: enter image description here

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

to make the corners of the suggestions rounded in ur optionsViewBuilder >Align>Material>Container

add decoration to the contianer

[image]

```
      return Align(
        alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
        child: Material(
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(         //<----- add decoration here
              border: Border.all(color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary.withOpacity(.4)),
              borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12.0)),
            ),
            color: greyMed,
            child: ConstrainedBox(
              constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 300, maxWidth: 235),
              child: ListView.builder(
                padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  final option = options.elementAt(index);
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text(
                      option.toString(),
                      style: TextStyle(color: textWhite),
                    ),
                    onTap: () {
                      onSelected(option);
                    },
                  );
                },
                itemCount: options.length,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
```